# Jssor Slider not working internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jssor

The jssor slide works fine in all browsers (Chrome, FF and Safari) except IE(11). The banner doesn't show the images (all is black) and only shows the loading.gif image frozen.
You can see the website [here](http://www.casamillan.es/dev/).

I've copied the exactly files and code from the demo content...

Suggestions? ;)

Comment: You might want to capture an image of the faulty page and put it into the question. then when you have fixed it, your question will still make sense to later readers; whereas the link to the page will soon get out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE can read 'width: 829px;' instead of 'width: 829'

Please replace,

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 829; height: 114px; overflow: hidden; ">
```

with

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 829px; height: 114px; overflow: hidden; ">
```